# Looping through pixels excluding an area

Tags: c#

I have the following code for looping pixels in an image:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);  
for (x = 0; x < pictureBox1.Image.Width; x += 1) 
{
     for (y = 0; y < pictureBox1.Image.Height; y += 1)
     {
          Color pixelColor = myBitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
          aws = pixelColor.GetBrightness();
     }
}
```

The above works. What if i want to exclude an area of the image. The area is an area selected by the user,for example:

```
from x=200&y=30 to x=250&y=30
from x=200&y=35 to x=250&y=35
from x=200&y=40 to x=250&y=40
from x=200&y=45 to x=250&y=45
```

How i loop all pixels except the one i wrote above?
Thank you!

Comment: `if(x > 200 && <250?)` not sure if im missing something here

Comment: Using `GetPixel` would be very slow especially if image is large..Use a pointer..

Comment: or [lockbits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do something like the following

```
        Rectangle rectToExclude = new Rectangle(200, 30, 250, 30);//rectangle to be excluded
        Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
        for (x = 0; x < pictureBox1.Image.Width; x += 1)
        {
            for (y = 0; y < pictureBox1.Image.Height; y += 1)
            {
                if (rectToExclude.Contains(x, y)) continue; // if in the exclude rect then continue without doing any effects
                Color pixelColor = myBitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
                aws = pixelColor.GetBrightness();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Wow! so simple and worked!!! I guess i can use other shapes too,other than rectangle. Thank all the others or contributing.Thank you Yazan.

Answer (score 2):

**Maybe write a function to test x and y like this:**

```
public static bool IsInArea(int testx, int testy, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    if (testx > x1 && testx < x2 && testy > y1 && testy < y2)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
BitmapData bmd = myBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, myBitmap.Width, myBitmap.Height),
                                    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                                    myBitmap.PixelFormat);

int PixelSize = 4;

unsafe
{
    for (int y = 0; y < bmd.Height; y++)
    {
        byte* row = (byte*)bmd.Scan0 + (y * bmd.Stride);

        for (int x = 0; x < bmd.Width; x++)
        {
            if (!IsInArea(x, y, 200, 30, 250, 30))
            {
                int b = row[x * PixelSize];         //Blue
                int g = row[x * PixelSize + 1];     //Green
                int r = row[x * PixelSize + 2];     //Red
                int a = row[x * PixelSize + 3];     //Alpha

                Color c = Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b);

                float brightness = c.GetBrightness();
            }

        }
    }
}

myBitmap.UnlockBits(bmd);
```

Comment: Can I suggest you just return the test in the if statement? should save a few computer cycles

Comment: `return (test1 && test2 etc);`

Comment: yep, you are right, but I would leave that to Theodoros80 to implement. :)

Comment: ok, I did not test it... this is just to give you an idea how to accomplish what you need...

Comment: @Theodoros80 - this will be much more efficient than yazan's answer as it gets all the bitmaps pixels at once instead of one at a time.

Comment: @Sayse yeap this could be true espesially with large images. As i told you i will give it a try.